# How to Join and Display Data from two models on a single razor page (no mvc)

Tags: syntax, foreign-keys, inner-join, razor-pages

I have two models (Child and Shot) that I would like to join so that I can display information on a single razor page.

This small historical view app basically has client demographics in one model (Model Name is Child) and client immunizations in another table (Model Name is Shot). I have an index page that a user will click a 'View Immunization Details' details button next to a client's ID number and client name. This will take them to the page where I would like the joined data to display.

The top half of the page will display the demographics (ID, name, address, date of birth, etc) from the Child model and the lower half of the page will display a table of any immunization info for that particular client (from the Shot model). (immunization date, dose, shot description, etc)

This is a one to many relationship between Child and Shot. One Child record can have many Shot records.

In reviewing how to get two models to display on one page I have only seen where the data did NOT need to be filtered by the results from one model. As stated above, I need to show ONLY the shots that pertain to a SINGLE client on the Details page, NOT all shots from the Shot table.

Here is my code as I have it so far:

First, the Child model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace HealthyShots.Models
{
    public class Child
    {
        [Key]
        [Display(Name ="Child ID")]
        public int ChildId { get; set; }
        public List<Shot> Shots { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="Last Name")]
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "MI")]
        public string? MiddleInitial { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return LastName + ", " + FirstName + " " + MiddleInitial;
            }
        }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string? Addr1 { get; set; }
        public string? Addr2 { get; set; }
        public string? City { get; set; }
        public string? State { get; set; }
        public string? Zip { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then, the Shot model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace HealthyShots.Models
{
    public class Shot
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public int ShotId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ChildId { get; set; }
        public Child Child { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        [Display(Name = "Immunization Date")]
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
        public string? Dose { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Shot Number")]
        public int? ShotNo { get; set; }
        [Display(Name ="Shot Description")]
        public string? ShotDesc { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then, my .cs (so far) for the Details razor page:

```
using HealthyShots.Data;
using HealthyShots.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace HealthyShots.Pages.Details
{
    public class DetailsModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public Child Child { get; set; }
        public Shot Shot { get; set; }
        

        public DetailsModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        
        public void OnGet(int Id)
        {
            _db.Child
                .Include(child => child.Shots)
                .FirstOrDefault(child => child.ChildId == Id);
        }

    }
}
```

And my razor view:

```
@page
@model HealthyShots.Pages.Details.DetailsModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Immunization Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Demographic Information</h4>
    <hr />

        <table class="table table-bordeless" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 10%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Child.ChildId"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Child.ChildId" disabled class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 30%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Child.LastName"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Child.LastName" disabled class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 30%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Child.FirstName"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Child.FirstName" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 5%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Child.MiddleInitial"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Child.MiddleInitial" disabled class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Child.BirthDate"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Child.BirthDate" type="date" disabled class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="table table-bordeless" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Child.Addr1"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Child.Addr1" disabled class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Child.Addr2"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Child.Addr2" disabled class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 25%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Child.City"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Child.City" disabled class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 5%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Child.State"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Child.State" disabled class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Child.Zip"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Child.Zip" disabled class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<br />
<br />


    <h4>Immunizations</h4>
    <hr />

          <table class="table table-bordeless" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 20%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Shot.Date"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Shot.Date" type="date" disabled class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Shot.Dose"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Shot.Dose" disabled class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 60%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Shot.ShotDesc"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Shot.ShotDesc" disabled class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </table>

    <a asp-page="/Children/Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

I know I am missing code. I have googled and searched here for how the foreign key works, but still don't fully understand it. I realize that I have to tell Visual Studio that the Id (in the Child model) must be the same as the ChildId (in the Shot model), but I am not sure WHERE to do that or WHAT the correct syntax is.

I also need a wee bit of guidance on how to reference these items on the razor page. Once they are joined via foreign key, can I just access them with asp tag helpers like I would if it were a single model being referenced? Like I have done in my code so far?

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide. I am a beginner, so please understand that when you frame your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create relationships using conventions

In EF Core one way to define entity relationships is using conventions. This means you have to add specific properties with specific names to your entities so that EF understands the relationship between them.

Example:

```cs
public class Child
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    public List<Shot> Shots { get; set; }
}

public class Shot
{
    public int ShotId { get; set; }

    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}
```

In the above scenario EF will automatically create a 1 to many relationship between `Shot` and `Child`. One shot is linked to one child but one child can be linked to multiple shots. `Shot.ChildId` will be a foreign key to `Child.ChildId`.

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions/one-to-many-relationship

### Loading related data from database

Now if you want to retrieve a specific child from database with all the related shots you can do:

```cs
var child = _db.Child
    .Include(child => child.Shots)
    .FirstOrDefault(child => child.ChildId == Id);
```

`Include` method tells EF to populate `Child.Shots` with all the shots that are related to this kid.

Similarly if you when you load the shots you can do:

```cs
var shots = _db.Shot
    .Include(shot => shot.Child)
    .ToList();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager

### Configure relationships manually

You can also configure relationships manually:

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration

Comment: Can you tell me exactly where in my code I should be placing the _db.Child
    .Include(child => child.Shots)
    .FirstOrDefault(child => child.ChildId == Id);

Comment: I am assuming it would go in the      public void OnGet(int Id) ? My view is still not pulling in the data. Not sure what is off.

Comment: Yes it should go inside `OnGet` method. Put a breakpoint inside that method and check what is going on. Does the `Id` parameter of `OnGet` method have a value? Is any `Child` with this id stored in the database? Also why is `Child` and `Shot` properties `virtual`?

Comment: Virtual was a try at figuring out the foreign key thing.

Comment: They shouldn't be virtual. Did you try to put a breakpoint inside `OnGet` method and see what you get?

Comment: I'm trying to. I have never done a breakpoint before. I added it, but when I hover over the statement, it doesn't show me anything. I must be missing something. Sorry, as I said beginner, very beginner.

Comment: OK. It says count=0 and 'empty'

Comment: I have updated all of my code above to what it looks like now.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my answer but you should do `Child = _db.Child.Include(child => child.Shots).FirstOrDefault(child => child.ChildId == Id);`. Now you are not setting the results to the `Child` property.

Comment: Almost there! That brought in the demographic info from the Child model onto the view page, but the shot data is empty yet.

Comment: There is also a } hanging out on my executed view page just below the hr/ of the Immunizations section. Not sure what is causing that.

Comment: Nevermind on the }. Just found that, at least.

Comment: The shot data is a collection so to display them you need a foreach loop: https://pastebin.com/yWkSasy3

Comment: I made the changes on your link and popped 6 errors. One for each one of the lowercase shot. in your view code. I changed those to uppercase, and the program will run, but now the table has disappeared under Immunizations on the view page.

Comment: Maybe the disappearing was a client that had no shots. I tried one that I know has 3 shots and I get 3 table rows, but nothing in them.

Comment: Try like this: https://pastebin.com/i41HujqY or even better this: https://pastebin.com/EhCFSeG6 to show "No data found" alert when the child has not done any shots.

Comment: You got it!! Thanks so much. Is the 'i' an incrementer?

Comment: It's basically a variable in a for-loop: https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/for-loop

Comment: Thanks so much for the link. Makes perfect sense. And also for all of your help yesterday! It is much appreciated. I learned a lot!

Comment: No problem and good luck on your programming journey!